# Knockout binding value not applying to model

Tags: knockout.js

I have written a custom binding. When I try to use it to create a table  no value appears in the appropriate cell. I know it is receiving a value using a log statement and it is doing what I need to in the function, but even if I try to return something nothing shows in the the table. What have I done incorrectly? I don't understand custom bindings that well.

```
         ko.bindingHandlers.sizeInMB = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor){
                    var size = valueAccessor();
                    if      (size>=1000000000){size=(size/1000000000).toFixed(2)+' GB';}
                    else if (size>=1000000){size=(size/1000000).toFixed(2)+' MB';}
                    else if (size>=1000){size=(size/1000000).toFixed(2)+' MB';}
                    else if (size>1){size=size/1000000+' MB';}
                    else if (size==1){size=size/1000000+' MB';}
                    else{size='0 MB';}
                //console.log(size);
                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {value: size});
            }
    };
        ko.bindingHandlers.fileType = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor){
                    var name = valueAccessor();
                    var type = name.split('.').pop();
                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {value: type});
            }
    };
<!-- ko foreach: multiFileData().fileArray -->
<tr>
<td><span class="attachName" data-bind="text:name"></span></td>
<td><span data-bind="sizeInMB: size"></span></td>
<td><span data-bind="fileType: name"></span></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the `value` binding to non-input elements. You probably want to use the `text` binding, or replace the `<span>` elements by `<input>`s.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.sizeInMB = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var size = valueAccessor();
    if (size >= 1000000000) {
      size = (size / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
    } else if (size >= 1000000) {
      size = (size / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    } else if (size >= 1000) {
      size = (size / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    } else if (size > 1) {
      size = size / 1000000 + ' MB';
    } else if (size == 1) {
      size = size / 1000000 + ' MB';
    } else {
      size = '0 MB';
    }
    //console.log(size);
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
      text: size
    });
  }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.fileType = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var name = valueAccessor();
    var type = name.split('.').pop();
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
      text: type
    });
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({ files: [ { name: "Some.Name", size: 1012302391 } ] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: files -->
<div>
  <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
  <span data-bind="sizeInMB: size"></span>
  <span data-bind="fileType: name"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```